# Сложный SQL запрос на вывод комментариев с количеством лайков и наличием пользовательского лайка на нём

Tags: sql, postgresql

Всем привет, такой вопрос: есть 4 таблицы которые связаны между собой, нужно написать запрос на вывод комментариев к игре (по id), а так же сколько лайков на каждом комментарии и лайкнул ли сам комментарий пользователь. с таблицей review связана таблица games по полю game_id. БД - postgresql15. Вот мои наработки в которых идёт только подсчёт лайков, но нет проверки поставил ли сам пользователь лайк на комментарий. Если что то надо уточнить, я уточню.

```
SELECT "review".id, "review".user_id, game_id, grade, "comment", "review".created_at, "user".username,
count(distinct "review_like".user_id)
FROM public.review
left outer join "user" on "user".id = "review".user_id
left outer join "review_like" ON  "review_like".review_id  = "review".id 
where "review".game_id = '6ad2dd8e-b42a-46de-b8d5-323cd221d39f' group by "review".id, "user"."username"
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035) Особенно пункты 5 и 3. И все ненужные для вопроса поля - убрать.

Comment: подзапросом посчитайте. и distinct там вроде и не нужен, вряд ли один юзер может постаивть несколько лайков одному  и тому же ревью?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT "review".id, "review".user_id, game_id, grade, "comment", "review".created_at, "user".username,
count(distinct "review_like".user_id),
sum(case when review_like.user_id=review.user_id then 1 else 0 end)
FROM public.review
left outer join "user" on "user".id = "review".user_id
left outer join "review_like" ON  "review_like".review_id  = "review".id 
where "review".game_id = '6ad2dd8e-b42a-46de-b8d5-323cd221d39f' group by "review".id, "user"."username"
```

Посчитаем количество лайков к обзору самого автора: `sum(case when review_like.user_id=review.user_id then 1 else 0 end)`

Упрощённый пример: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d2854/5

Comment: Простите, но я забыл уточнить у меня id пользователя типа uuid. И ещё вопрос, что за таблица "author"?

Comment: на счёт таблицы автора я понял, осталось разобраться с наличием пользовательского лайка, я попробовал этот вариант, он не совсем корректно работает sum(case when review_like.user_id=review.user_id then 1 else 0 end)

Comment: а как именно "не совсем корректно"?

Comment: для всех отзывов считает правильно, кроме того, который оставил сам пользователь и лайк на нём, там как будто выводит

Comment: "поставил ли сам пользователь" - пользователь-автор ревью или пользователь, под которым мы в данный момент зашли?

Comment: Автор ревью, ставит лайк своему же комментарию @zufir

Comment: ну да, если автор ревью поставит автор своему же комментарию - sum(case when review_like.user_id=review.user_id then 1 else 0 end) будет 1, если нет - 0. Комментарий и ревью - одно и то же?

Comment: Комментарий и ревью это одно и то же, у меня получается сумма всех лайков если пользователь лайкнул свой коммент

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149038/discussion-between-zufir-and-mokybrow).

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d2854/5 - посмотрите  упрощённый пример